# mysql create multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a project in which i need to create two tables in one query.

I'm writing like this:

```
DROP TABLE Employee;

CREATE TABLE Employee(
Employee_Id CHAR(12)NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
First_name CHAR(30),
Last_name CHAR(30),
Address VARCHAR(50),
City CHAR,
State CHAR,
Salary INT,
Gender CHAR,
Age INT
);

DROP TABLE Job;

CREATE TABLE job(
Exempt_Non_Exempt_Status tinyint(1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Job_title CHAR,
Job_description CHAR
);
```

But this gives an error like "Unknown table 'job'" even if I didn't create it.

Comment: Do the tables exist before you try to drop them?

Comment: @Adi, you can also use `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the **[`DROP Table IF EXISTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/drop-table.html)** syntax:

> Use IF EXISTS to prevent an error from occurring for tables that do not exist.

Something like:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS
  Employee ;

CREATE TABLE Employee(
...
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS
  Job ;

CREATE TABLE Job(
...
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You cant drop a table that doesnt exist. Use the:

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Job;
```